Can the Summary section be modified during examination?
So I read that the Summary section is usually drafted from the independent claims.
This is the case with my provisional application, where the Summary section is nearly word for word identical to the independent claims.
But of course, claims may be modified or discarded during examination.
If the independent claims are indeed modified or discarded during examination, then the Summary section would now be inconsistent.
At this point, will the Summary section be re-written or left as is?
But I thought that the specifications of a patent application, which includes the Summary section, cannot be modified?

You are asking about a provisional but talking about examination. Which type of application is the question regarding?

It is for the non-provisional application that will be filed on top of the provisional.

It is not required to have a summary of the invention (and I think you've just stumbled on another good reason to avoid having one):
Is the "Brief Summary of the Invention" section actually required?

But I thought that the specifications of a patent application, which includes the Summary section, cannot be modified?

One can make modifications to the specifications of a patent application provided they do not constitute "new matter".
For example, if one wants to add something to the summary it must already have been stated elsewhere, and in the same combination.

Could you explicitly answer the question posed in the title?

@EricS Added answer to the question posed.
